# Formula : (Exact) Sum of $1^1+2^2+3^3+..+n^n$ (modulo $10^m$) with relatively small $m$

Tags: power-series, diophantine-equations

I am trying to **programmatically** solve mathematical problem - get sum of all powers from $1^1$ to $1000^{1000}$. So far I have found solution by simply summing powers, but it takes way to long time and not getting any near to final 1000 integer.

Question - is there a formula for this case : get sum of all number powers 
$1^1 + 2^2 + 3^3 + .. 1000^{1000}$ ?

Comment: This sum has thousands of digits. Do you need them all? Or just the number modulus something?

Comment: Yes - summ has more than 3000 digits. It would be nice to have all digits, but actually I need only last 10 digits.

Comment: See http://oeis.org/A001923

Comment: $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^nk^k\simeq n^n$

Comment: @Lucian Sorry, but approximation is not an option..

Comment: in Pari/GP the following  `m=10^10;sum(k=1,1000,Mod(k,m)^k)` gives in a part of a second `Mod(9110846700, 10000000000)` so your result (the ten last digits) is $9110846700$ . To have it to the last 100 digits you do   `m=10^100;sum(k=1,1000,Mod(k,m)^k)` and get the analoguous way
$69769065444739780\\17455720367929981\\79602304178585262\\ 67972712834657894\\98383642350667978\\127819110846700$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We define the following [sequence $\text{(A001923)}$](http://oeis.org/A001923).

> $$
> S_n := \sum_{k=1}^{n} k^k = 1 + 2^2 + \dots + n^n.
> $$

To find a formula of $S_n$ was a problem proposed by G. W. Wishard in 1945 in the [American Mathematical Monthly (AMM)](http://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/american-mathematical-monthly). It would be nice to have some results like [Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber's_formula), but unfortunately for this problem we don't have a formula like that.

Wishard was given the lower and upper bounds $n^n < S_n < 2n^n$ for $n>1$. As an answer to Wishard's problem F. Underwood was given the following better [lower and an upper bounds](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2306261) for $S_n$ in 1946. For $n>2$,
$$
n^n\left(1+\frac{1}{4(n-1)}\right) < S_n < n^n\left(1+\frac{2}{e(n-1)}\right).
$$

---

[The Euler Project Problem 48](https://projecteuler.net/problem=48) is to find the last ten digits of $S_{1000}$. The problem was published in 2003.

It is easy to calculate the sum using computer algebra systems like *Maple* or *Mathematica*. You can run the following Mathematica code in [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/):

> `Sum[k^k,{k,1,1000}]`

You can check the result [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum[k%5Ek%2C%7Bk%2C1%2C1000%7D]). $S_{1000}$ has $3001$ digits and these are the following.

$$\begin{align}
S_{1000} = 1000368199144695177095375011227646795567793680622934654583760988\\
1002349107477161943814286590995278459458699426431912908947203429\\
7990640767964725986043423846803832604080969103761537037623771364\\
8510063115732951461774246705584266865759601815843666442832284556\\
8803131145481515391909753984854966455765134658585827123364011662\\
2195618817344953167410268890832176466302030669977040862534076609\\
1595022791379368098369306375602813856646358773751558775213460225\\
7965798465833340073493586243423393329813345712378888092831033487\\
6026136017595081560917946402687100524365210998086355214201424290\\
3434068560936573231079342194031864413918101238151056509267393515\\
7603928424725013915940734630015218438110737670217110263075046957\\
3346789782186690664846982834660741296739580179779168360983472243\\
2241952845352564681868240369569566192825555323558078061997527689\\
9838488633747867893315815652520591726143394246009861432592331675\\
8337107036262555453185205416611714885822950858158961433759446327\\
7554380518380921301218836327102231407332201109740102580216469298\\
3317669206196460837907328076273606144280851715650062897285086889\\
6422679964719258292405858953075067457838536556187855958968575622\\
5692348914746922810913915619834754117648358035814128670294158565\\
6699420877362863909422415472260150044713306301130720427042889050\\
4214262819377191859457430220214720118848634591319083375230747696\\
6010547423928871063118783026036381319039052008252072057933666712\\
9189462333127936970940742241878720459709764443092427821877383202\\
5749008082433007499169869823956112581112760786390035522173784669\\
0567707344074494145266662103839812840216303448476913957072355732\\
7166270983722452230467929197472591131574258240648583314154009432\\
7821304295463505357404520998451222126424190355017841682455141254\\
8637590007779082539288247751653566899882749594405895102587985539\\
5277094935100495464454272656174783991071882386817712159042341193\\
9224748975107908594805594509880561796372292846955426378221762516\\
0428008228845552540344494860195267115187092227766195753907211126\\
6461501406147442339747652734756199643118528586141678196683401247\\
3048771016200679352998575882065367727437956331349545452663271872\\
3482339494825759821076401694316043456512117937935456463521463021\\
1977266949835589291323575761885949775166307342128638694561642055\\
2553676731129813718251149464946366307375921921305682356166777609\\
3739425742883930712609962163464088038826569132032160692637206183\\
0859429879736845842764917848431154720779004016925956941192735535\\
1102599126544603936628892174358133320008371710524117150460688354\\
3418862024047552177055263424469501298905901938158245938633694105\\
0248151666798136891566683411977134750943899048871267944689018938\\
5047505001120522574245555562575056021323038791033798395033324502\\
0653238989115507013882956277763880795687210857196493893142656713\\
1059662754221446059880589396006036042269214014020965192942504886\\
7029798339635327946045314237554226788198919748178978067895509376\\
3193658603690898474826976906544473978017455720367929981796023041\\
785852626797271283465789498383642350667978127819110846700.\,\phantom{.......}
\end{align}$$

From here we know that the last ten digits are

> $$9110846700.$$

---

Another interesting problem is to find the prime factorization of $S_{n}$ values. The only known [prime values of the sequence](http://oeis.org/A073825) are $S_2, S_5, S_6, S_{10}, S_{30}$, and according to [this website](http://www.primepuzzles.net/puzzles/puzz_404.htm), there is no other prime element for $n<28000$.

According to [factordb](http://oeis.org/A073825), $S_{1000}$ has the form
$$S_{1000} = 2^2 \cdot 5^2 \cdot 344251 \cdot C_{\langle2993\rangle},$$
where $C_{\langle2993\rangle}$ is a composite number with $2993$ digits, without known prime factor. I've made a trial division and I've found no prime factors of $C_{\langle2993\rangle}$ upto $3.735 \cdot 10^8$.

You could find the digits of $S_{1000}$ in the factordb [here](http://factordb.com/index.php?showid=1100000000791357934), and the digits of $C_{\langle2993\rangle}$ [here](http://factordb.com/index.php?showid=1100000000791357936).

Comment: Please see my answer below which suggests that a Faulhaber-like form is possible, however instead of using polynomials but power series.

Answer (score 1):

Since you only need the last 10 digits, you can calculate the sum modulo `10^10`. You can do each term individually in around `logn` time, using the 'fast mod-exponentiation' algorithm, and using standard 64 bit integers.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring

Answer (score 0):

No I guess there is none...if you are coding then just use one of the suitable library function to do so..

Comment: I have searched for it, but I doubt that there will be any variable that can hold number with >3000 digits.. (Code written in C#)

Comment: It's not possible for a normal computer to do so

Comment: At max you can use long int

Comment: No - it is possible. I must be! :D I am trying to solve Project Euler math problem Nr.48.. And no - in C# long can hold only <20 digits !

Comment: @KristapsVilerts [It is possible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624815/how-can-i-use-bigint-with-c), with a built-in data type.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you. From other people answers I assume that I can get a _smarter_ solution by calculation only several last digits. Right now I am holding all values in arrays and doing operations with them and I think that just simply calculation everthing with BigInteger will be the solution for me.

Comment: in Pari/GP the following  `m=10^10;sum(k=1,1000,Mod(k,m)^k)` gives in a part of a second `Mod(9110846700, 10000000000)` so your result (the ten last digits) is $9110846700$ .

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a function $f(x)=a_0+a_1 (x-2)+ a_2 (x-2)^2 + ... $ having a power series to allow computations $$f(a) - f(b) \Rightarrow \sum_{k=a}^{b-1} k^k = a^a+ (a+1)^{a+1} + ... + (b-1)^{b-1} $$
Thus this function resembles the Faulhaber-polynomials for summing of like powers, but a series instead of polynomials.

I have estimated the first $16$ coefficients of the power series -however by a process which involved Borel-summation (this is because hypergeometric series were involved: a summation $\sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k \zeta(-k)$ where the $b_k$ come from another basic process.)

---

Results were

```
   function-call \\ Pari/GP-output       \\ expected value
    ----------\\ ----------------------- \\ ---------------
    f(1)-f(2) \\  %1599 = 0.999998176060 \\ 1
    f(2)-f(3) \\  %1600 = 3.99997420277  \\ 4
    f(3)-f(4) \\  %1601 = 26.9802071641  \\ 27
    f(1)-f(4) \\  %1602 = 31.9801795429  \\ 1+4+27 = 32
    f(4)-f(5) \\  %1603 = 253.511224675  \\ 256
    f(1)-f(5) \\  %1604 = 285.491404218  \\ 1+4+27+256 = 288
```

If all things are correct, the function call $f(1)$ should represent the value for the divergent series $1^1+2^2+3^3+ ...$ and I get

```
     f(1)     \\  %1605 = 0.920504741712
```

but I've no indication whether this is a good approximation to the divergent sum since the further coefficients of $f()$ must be determined ahead.

---

The first 16 coefficents of $f()$ are 
$ \displaystyle \qquad \small {f(x) \approx -0.0794934343476 - 1.65692140370 (x-2) - 1.11812836411 (x-2)^2 \\ - 0.684761038796 (x-2)^3 - 0.326230447867 (x-2)^4 - 0.139731759201 (x-2)^5 \\
- 0.0503638959048 (x-2)^6 - 0.0170549876382 (x-2)^7 - 0.00492289036806 (x-2)^8 \\
- 0.00142215527729 (x-2)^9 - 0.000328786011807 (x-2)^{10} - 0.0000893598385901 (x-2)^{11} \\
- 0.0000136960991952 (x-2)^{12} - 0.00000506658346922 (x-2)^{13} + 0.0000000670037315633 (x-2)^{14} \\
- 0.000000418378602689 (x-2)^{15} + O((x-2)^{16})} $