# Is there any kind of formula to estimate this $1^1+2^2+3^3+...+n^n$?

Tags: summation, infinity

Is there a efficient formula to calculate this sum ? $$S = 1^1+2^2+3^3+...+n^n$$ , or it simply diverges ?

Comment: You can compare with $1/n$ and show it will diverge. Do you mean for finite $n$

Comment: It depends on how tightly you want to estimate it. Generically, the last few terms are so, so much larger than the previous terms that a pretty good estimate is $n^n$ or $n^n + (n-1)^{n-1}$.

Comment: It obviously diverges, for its general term does not converges to zero ;)

Comment: Efficient in what sense ?

Comment: Is the question about a closed formula or about convergence ?

Comment: About a formula

Comment: The sequence is http://oeis.org/A001923 where some references are given.  For $n=100$ it is $100371115746176445351701210713361941528546861949073514542015172437236580034634746971244943788132460150776779198800002366059871900041784732217539059306483834977865973576751345853385981719448969027641920$

Comment: The question is a duplicate of a couple of similar questions, see for instance https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1487637/1714

Answer (score 7):

The function $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n k^k$ has been studied often, see [here](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C5%2C32%2C288%2C3413&language=german&go=Suche) for references. The question for a formula or an estimate is the well known [Problem 4155](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2306261?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) by G. W. Wishard, published in Amer. Math. Monthly, 53 (1946), 471. A solution was given there by F. Underwood.

Edit: The linked paper shows the estimate
$$
n^n\left( 1+\frac{1}{4(n-1)}\right)<S_n<n^n\left( 1+\frac{2}{e(n-1)}\right).
$$
I am thankful to Ross Millikan, who has provided this estimate.

Comment: The linked paper defines $S_n$ as the sum up to $n$ terms and shows$$n^n\left(1+\frac 1{4(n-1)}\right) \lt S_n \lt n^n\left(1+\frac 2{e(n-1)}\right)$$

Comment: @RossMillikan Thank you for helping me ( I have no access here to this paper right now, and did not remember all details).

Comment: You are welcome to copy the expression into your answer.  Sometimes comments disappear.

Comment: I seem to have a process to determine a power series $f(x) = a_0 + a_1 (x-2) + a_2 (x-2)^2 + ... $ such that $f(a) - f(b) = a^a + (a+1)^{a+1} + ... + (b-1)^{b-1}$ This is somehow like Faulhaber's formula but a series instead of a polynomial. See for a short example https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2373488/1714

Answer (score 4):

Claim $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1^1+2^2+3^3+\cdots+n^n}{(n+1)^n}= \frac{1}{e}$$

We will do that by using [Cesaro-Stolz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) the discrete version of the L'Hospital's rule.

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1^1+2^2+3^3+\cdots+n^n}{(n+1)^n}&=^{\text{CS}}\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{(n+2)^{n+1}   -(n+1)^n}= \\
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{(1+\frac{1}{n+1})^{n+1}   -(n+1)^{-1}}\\
&=\frac{1}{e}
\end{align*}