# What is $\sum_{k=1}^n k^k$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

As the title says, how can I explicitly express $\sum_{k=1}^n k^k$ in terms of a function $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ ?

I've tried simplifying the expression $n^n+(n-1)^{(n-1)}+\cdots+1$ but I came up with nothing. Is it even possible to find such a function? Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The hope that this sum has a closed form formula is very very tiny...

Comment: @JeanMarie Unfortunately I have to disagree with you. The vitamin theorem states that if you define a function $\mathfrak s(n) :=\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^k$ and then write a small wikipedia article about it, this expression has a closed form, namely $\mathfrak s(n)$.

Comment: @JeanMarie okay, thanks for the comment, that makes sense. I've tried to look up on internet if someone asked the same question before but I've found nothing (not only nobody found a solution, but nobody has even asked this question before), hence my curiosity. I've figured out that asking here wouldn't have hurt.

Comment: I don't know of an exact formula, but Wishard, G. W., & Underwood, F. (1946). *4155.* The American Mathematical Monthly, 53(8), 471, establishes explicit lower and upper bounds for the sum of the form $n^n \left(1 + O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)$.

Comment: ... hmm... hard to choose between $\mathfrak s$ and A001923....

Comment: @vitamind: let me disagree with you. Special functions are excluded from the definition of closed-form expressions. If you allow them what you get is an *analytical* expression.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Formula : (Exact) Sum of $1^1+2^2+3^3+..+n^n$ (modulo $10^m$) with relatively small $m$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1487637/formula-exact-sum-of-112233-nn-modulo-10m-with-relatively-sm)

Comment: @HansLundmark thanks! That's really useful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typing the first four entries (i.e., $1,5,32,288$) into the [On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org/), I found sequence [A001923](https://oeis.org/A001923). There's a number of interesting properties which may address some underlying questions you had about this sequence (but no closed formula).

I hope you find it helpful in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting [this paper](http://ijpam.eu/contents/2007-36-2/9/9.pdf), in $1946$ Underwood established upper and lower bounds for $n\geq2$
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{4 (n-1)}\right) n^n<S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n k^k<\left(1+\frac{2}{e (n-1)}\right) n^n$$ Just for your curiosity, plot the three curves on a logarithmic scale.

So, for a given value $a$ of $S_n$, it is easy to compute $n$
$$n\sim\frac{\log (a)}{W(\log (a))}$$ where $W(.)$ is Lambert function.

For example, for $a=10^{1000}$, we should find, as a real $n=386.522$.

Checking
$$S_{386}=2.65\times 10^{998} \qquad \text{and} \qquad S_{387}=2.78\times 10^{1001} $$

Comment: Underwood's upper bound is $$\left( {1 + \frac{2}{{e(n - 1)}}} \right)n^n .$$

Comment: @Gary. Thanks for pointing the typo.

Comment: There is also an asymptotic expansion of the form $$
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {k^k }  \sim n^n \left( {1 + e^{ - 1}\frac{1}{n}  + \left( {\frac{{e^{ - 1} }}{2} + e^{ - 2} } \right)\frac{1}{{n^2 }} +  \cdots } \right)
$$ as $n\to +\infty$.

Comment: @Gary. Any reference fot this one ? Thanks

Comment: I do not know, I did not try to find one. I just derived it myself.

Comment: @Gary. Always impressive !

Comment: Note also that $$
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {k^k }  \geq  n^n \left( {1 + \frac{1}{n}\left( {1 - \frac{1}{n}} \right)^{n - 1} } \right) > n^n \left( {1 + e^{ - 1} \frac{1}{n}} \right)
$$ which is better than Underwood's.