# Is there a closed form for this sum of $k²+k^k$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, closed-form

The sum in particular is: $$\sum_{k=1}^n (k^2+k^k)$$

I tried looking for a closed form for $\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^k$ but from here I'm certain it doesn't exist. Even though maybe a closed form for the other one does exist. And the method I'm suggested is method of differences, which I tried factoring or try looking for that difference as the sum of squares but those are the only ideas that came to me.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4098476/42969

Comment: Note: If $\sum a_k$ has a closed form and $\sum b_k$ doesn't, then $\sum (a_k+b_k)$ cannot have a closed form either.

Comment: I said I knew about that page in the post and that there is no closed form for the sum of $k^k$ but I was asking if there is one for the sum of $k^k+k^2$.

Comment: Oh okay that's the answer I'm looking for. Thanks @HagenvonEitzen

Comment: $\sum k^k$ is tabulated at https://oeis.org/A001923 – no formula is given there, which strongly suggests there isn't one.

Comment: I literally said so in my post. Do people just read a few lines and post whatever related?

Comment: No, Acedium, what happened is that people found it hard to believe that you didn't know that there's a closed form for $\sum k^2$, or that you knew that but didn't know that since there's a closed form for $\sum k^2$ there can't be a closed form for $\sum(k^2+k^k)$ unless there's a closed form for $\sum k^k$. So, please, don't slag off users who are trying to help you, even if they're having trouble seeing exactly what help you need.